# The number of days from a stem-leaf diagram

Tags: statistics

[image]

For part C
I can see the same of passengers for the two ferries are $30$ ,$43$ and $45$

Then can i say it happens at 3 days ??

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: ^^[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Doesn't have to be 3 days, which is the point of the question, they might not ever have had the same number of passengers, so the range of possibilities is 0 to 3.